# Why does allocating a large number of VBOs cause performance issues?

Tags: opengl

I have an application that allocates ~300 VBOs.  However, only 40 of these are used for draw commands each frame.  I've verified this with an OpenGL profiler.

I notice that if I decrease the number of VBOs, performance is much improved.  However, given that most of the VBOs are unused most of the time, I'm surprised this is a problem.  I'd assume that most of the VBOs don't have memory allocated to them, since I haven't even called glBufferData on the unused VBOs.

Does anyone know why having extra unused VBOs would cause a performance hit?  I'm guessing it's probably driver-dependent (I have a Nvidia 460GTX).

Also, I'd be interested in ways to combine a bunch of particle systems (most of which are unused during any given frame) into a single VBO so that I don't run into this issue.

**EDIT**: It turns out that performance issue wasn't related to the VBOs.  However, I learned a lot about streaming data into VBOs while investigating.  This article was very interesting: http://onrendering.blogspot.com/2011/10/buffer-object-streaming-in-opengl.html.

Comment: Driver might still be reserving something for them possibly.

Comment: @Jesus Yeah, I'm pretty sure it's a driver issue. Using 300 VBOs is boneheaded anyway, so I'll think of another scheme.

Comment: You could probably just reuse some of the VBOs if you're only using about 40 per draw call.

Comment: I'm thinking about using one big VBO as a circular buffer instead.  A bit more complicated, but I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: I have also noticed that my program works slower once I make a large VBO, about 150k polys, and it even slows evenything down when that VBO is not rendering :( GTS 250 )

Comment: It's strange, I have around ~4000 VBO's for mobile OpenGL ES and it works perfectly. Can you share your code or make some example I will try to investigate?

Comment: @SAKristT It turns out that the problem wasn't the VBOs. 300 VBOs worked fine for me after I fixed the actual issue.  4000 VBOs on mobile is just further proof that the number of VBOs you allocate doesn't really affect performance all that much.

Comment: @MattFichman Could you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the number of VBOs was not the cause of the performance bottleneck in my case. In fact, it seems most OpenGL implementations handle large numbers of VBOs pretty well. I tested on a 2009 MacBook Air and an Nvidia GTX 460.

Tangentially related: if you're using many VBOs, there's usually a way to avoid that and gain some efficiency. In my case, I used a single streaming VBO to render particles from multiple different particle systems, instead of dedicating a VBO to each particle system. This reduced the number of batches/draw calls, and freed up some CPU cycles.

Here's more information on VBO streaming:
http://onrendering.blogspot.com/2011/10/buffer-object-streaming-in-opengl.html